# How to open a specific conversation window in Skype for Business from inside an iOS app using openUrl method?

Tags: ios, openurl, lync-2013, skype-for-business

I have a question on the upgrade of Lync 2013 to Skype for Business on iOS app.

Earlier, when Lync 2013 app was there and installed on a device, calling sip://emailid using openURL method from an app used to open the Lync app with a conversation window to the person whose email was emailid

With the new Skype for Business app, it is no longer happening. It just opens the Skype with the Skype app screen showing recent conversation windows. It does not open the conversation window of specific person.

How can this be achieved for Skype for Business app?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For skype you can open the conversation with:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:USERNAME_OR_EMAIL?chat"]];
```

I do not have a Skype for Business account, so I cannot test it, but give this a go:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sip:USERNAME_OR_EMAIL?chat"]];
```